# How can I pull from one remote and push to another with git?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a contributor to my github repository who has a fork and is working on a branch. I want to pull their branch to my own branch and make modifications, but still track theirs.

Can I configure git so that while I'm on branch `foo`,

- `git pull` pulls from `contributor/foo` and
- `git push` pushes to `origin/foo`

This is similar to but distinct from the question [How can I push to one url and pull from another using one remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903129/how-to-push-to-one-remote-repo-and-pull-from-another) because that question is looking to use the same remote name.

Comment: Check this out.  I think the answer to my question is exactly what you need:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420662/git-mirror-on-pull-origin-on-push

Comment: You can always just go `git push origin foo`  ... actually I always use that form as it's more of a pain to recover from pushing to the wrong place than it is to type those things out

Answer (score 2):

You can set the upstream branch to contributor/foo

```
git checkout foo
git branch -u foo contributor/foo
```

That supposes you have a remote `contributor` first:

```
git remote add contributor https://github.com/user/fork_repo
```

And you can make sure a [`git push` is always done on `origin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18562564/6309):

```
git config remote.pushdefault origin
```