# Automatically update upstream branches

Tags: git

I have a repository (`origin`) that has been forked (in GitHub terms) from another repository (`upstream`). I do all the development in topic branches and never touch the branches present in the upstream repository (`master`, `developement`, `1.x`, etc.).

This is an example of the branches in my repository

```
$ git branch -a     # plus hand annotations
  development   [upstream-maintained: should always be == upstream/development]
  feature-1     [mine: should track origin/feature-1]
  feature-2     [mine: should track origin/feature-2]
* master        [upstream-maintained: should always be == upstream/master]
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/development
  remotes/origin/feature-1
  remotes/origin/feature-2
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/development
  remotes/upstream/gh-pages    [I do not care about this..]
  remotes/upstream/master
  remotes/upstream/stable-1.x  [...nor I care about these two..]
  remotes/upstream/stable-2.x  [...stable-* branches]
```

After I fetch from the upstream repository, I have to go through the tedious task of updating all the *upstream-maintained* branches: I switch to `master`, I `merge --ff-only upstream/master` and push to origin. This must be repeated for every upstream-maintained branch I care about. Please note that `merge --ff-only` always works because I never touch those branches.

I would like `git pull` to do all these tedious updates for me.

Is there a way to teach git that the upstream-maintained branches should be pushed to `origin` but pulled and tracked from `upstream`?

Comment: Are these two threads of any use?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577874/git-automatically-fast-forward-all-tracking-branches-on-pull and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches. Cheers!

Comment: @MBlanc, not really. Those questions deal with a single remote, while here I have two different remotes: one to pull from and one to push to. Thanks for the links though, the git-up tools seems nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in "[How can I pull from one remote and push to another with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24337920/6309)", you can:

- make sure to push to origin:

  ```
  git config remote.pushdefault origin
  git config push.default matching
  ```
- setup the upstream branch:

  ```
  git fetch upstream
  git branch -u upstream/master foo
  ```

Note that you should rebase your `topic` branches on top of `upstream/master` (not merge), in order to not have merge commits in your pull requests.
That means `git push -f` for updating your fork remote branch (that will update the pull request automatically)

You can force a rebase either through:

```
git config autosetuprebase remote
# or 

git branch.foo.rebase true
```

---

For example:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so>git clone https://github.com/gioele/offlineimap.git
Cloning into 'offlineimap'...
remote: Counting objects: 9445, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3701/3701), done.
remote: Total 9445 (delta 4962), reused 9445 (delta 4962)
Receiving objects: 100% (9445/9445), 5.75 MiB | 2.18 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4962/4962), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so>cd offlineimap

C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so\offlineimap>git remote add upstream https://github.com/offlineimap/offlineimap.git
```

Lets see what master refers to for now:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so\offlineimap>git branch -avvv
* master                  1746676 [origin/master] Make IDLE mode to work again
  remotes/origin/HEAD     -> origin/master

C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so\offlineimap>git config --local -l
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/gioele/offlineimap.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
remote.upstream.url=https://github.com/offlineimap/offlineimap.git
remote.upstream.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Let's make origin as the destination for a push:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so\offlineimap>git config push.default matching
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so\offlineimap>git config remote.pushdefault origin
```

Let's change the upstream branch:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so\offlineimap>git fetch upstream
remote: Counting objects: 55, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
remote: Total 55 (delta 25), reused 1 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (55/55), done.
From https://github.com/offlineimap/offlineimap
 * [new branch]      master     -> upstream/master

C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so\offlineimap>git branch -u upstream/master master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from upstream.
```

The `master` branch is set as monitoring `upstream/master`:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so\offlineimap>git br -avvv
* master                    1746676 [upstream/master: behind 10] Make IDLE mode to work again
```

Now a `git pull` (or better, a `git pull --rebase`) will pull from `upstream`:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so\offlineimap>git pull --rebase
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded master to 6bd76fed5a7e1e24310517b3510c465929870c08.
```

(and `6bd76fed5a7e1e24310517b3510c465929870c08` was `upstream/master` commit)

A `git push` would still push to origin:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\so\offlineimap>git push
remote: Permission to gioele/offlineimap.git denied to VonC.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gioele/offlineimap.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

(normal, since I am not `gioele`, I don't have write access to that repo)

Comment: Shouldn't the branches in the first command be swapped? `git branch -u upstream/master master`

Comment: Also, once I use `git config branch.master.remote origin`, `git push` refuses to push anything because "Everything is up-to-day" while upstream has two more commits.

Comment: @gioele if you don't pull/rebase first, then yes, a push would do nothing.

Comment: I tried again and did a pull first and it did not work. You can try using the current situation at https://github.com/gioele/offlineimap.git as `origin` and https://github.com/offlineimap/offlineimap.git as `upstream`. branch `master` and `next` are upstream-maintained and will not be pulled/pushed using your configuration.

Comment: @gioele I have fixed the exact sequence of commands to apply, and make a complete example out of your two repos: it works just fine.

Comment: yes, now everything is working as intended. Thank you.