# Methods to make git pull from one remote and push to another remote?

Tags: git-push, git-pull, git-remote

I have two remotes origin and fork. What I want to achieve is to make `git pull` pull from origin and make `git push` push to fork.

1. One approach is set different URLs for pull and push in
   `.git/config`. `url` is for pull. `pushurl` is for push. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7420741/431698 mentions this method.
2. The other is to use `git remote set-url` to set `url` and `git remote set-url --push` to set `pushurl`. This approach basically does the same thing as method 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15903520/431698 mentions this method.
3. Use `remote.pushdefault`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18562564/431698 mentions this method.

Is there any method to achieve my goal?

Comment: Add both repositories as remote.

Comment: @tkausl, can you give more details?